# WordPress Pagination on Page

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code on a WordPress page. It basically just grabs 3 posts and displays them as well as the page content itself up top. What I want to add is pagination so that a user can flick through all the posts, how do I get this working with custom loops like this?

```
    <?PHP

        get_header();

        /* Template Name: News */

    ?>

    <div style="padding: 0 20px;">


        <div class="box clearfix side" style="margin:10px 0;">

        <div style="float:left;width:628px;">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?><?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' <small>[', ']</small>'); ?></h2>

        <?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>


                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p>Pages: ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>


                    <hr />

                </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<hr />

        <?php $blog_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3'); while ($blog_query->have_posts()) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>



                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>



        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($blog_query->have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
            {
                wp_pagenavi();
            }
            ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                <h2>oooops!!!</h2>


                <?php endif; ?>


        </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <?PHP

        get_footer();

    ?>
```

Comment: any updates? need this for a client project asap. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to do something like this:

```
<?php $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; ?>        

        <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged)); while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
        {
            wp_pagenavi();
        }
        ?>

        <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah so basically you have to declare the global wp_query and set it inside a temp va. Pretty sucky :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not re-inventing the wheel a little here? Why not set the number of posts to display in the admin, then use WP's native paging for the blog?

Comment: Doesn't matter if I set the number in the admin or the code, and use the native pagination. The problem is that it's not showing up or when I manually type in the /page/2/ in the url it's not showing the next page of posts. So something is up, but what?

Comment: What is it showing? 404? Is this a page template or the standard `index.php`? Pagination will only work on a standard `have_posts()` loop inside `index.php`

Comment: it's just showing the same content so essentially it's ignoring the url, but it's also not showing the pagination!

Comment: Switch to the default theme (TwentyTen with 3.0), and see if everything is working OK. Have you set a static front page in your reading settings?